# change show for loop foreach

Tags: php, foreach

i have

```
    $arr = array(1Atlanta, 2Chicago, 3Dallas, 4Detroit, 5Boston, 6Colorado, 7New York, 8San D, 9, 10 ...);
<table>
  <tr>
    foreach ($arr as $i => $value) {
        echo $value;
       if ($i % 10 == 0) { 
         echo "</tr> <tr>"
       }

    }
  </tr>
</table>
```

this show me

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

etc

how can i make this:

```
1 11 21 etc...
2 21 22 etc...
3 31 32 etc...
4 41 42 etc..
etc...
```

for example for 253 value? [1-253] 
i must get the value from database, so i must use foreach, not for, and place sequentially from top to bottom, but not from left to right 
thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code -- feel free to tweak it to your liking:

```
<?php
$upper_bound = 253;

for ($i = 1; $i < 26; $i++){
  echo $i . " : ";

  for ($j = 0,$x = 1; $j < 10 ; $j++,$x++){
    $n =  $i * 10 + $x ;
    if ($n > $upper_bound){
      break;
    }
    echo $n ." ";
  }

  echo "<br />";
}

?>


    Output:

    1 : 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
2 : 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 
3 : 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
4 : 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 
5 : 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 
6 : 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 
7 : 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 
8 : 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 
9 : 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 
10 : 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 
11 : 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 
12 : 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 
13 : 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 
14 : 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 
15 : 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 
16 : 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 
17 : 171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 
18 : 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 
19 : 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 
20 : 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 
21 : 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 
22 : 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 
23 : 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 
24 : 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 
25 : 251 252 253
```

Comment: thanks, but i must use loop foreach. i get the value from database, this is list of city in USA. i would like place sequentially from top to bottom, but not from left to right

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but should be something close to what you want.

```
$width = 10; // display 10 columns
$arr = array(...);
$rows = ceil(count($arr) / $width); // how many rows there'll be. e.g. 11 fields = 11 / 10 round up = 2 rows.

echo '<table>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) { // row counter
   echo '<tr>';
   for ($j = 0; $j < $columns; $j++) { // column counter
      echo '<td>', $arr[($i * $width) + ($j * $width)], '</td>';
   }
   echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

---

Fine, if it has to be a foreach loop, with an unknown number of elements, you'll have to massage the data into a column-based format BEFORE doing any kind of output. You could build the individual rows as strings, but I'm building them into an array in case you might need the columnar format later on.

```
$arr = array(...); // your source data
$width = 10;
$rows = ceil(count($array) / $width);

$sorted_data = array();

$cur_row = 0;
foreach($arr as $val) {
   $sorted_data[$cur_row][] = $val;
   $cur_row++;
   if ($cur_row >= $rows) {
      $cur_row = 0;
   }
}

echo '<table>';
foreach($sorted_data as $idx => $row) { // start a row
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $val) { // output the individual values in the row
        echo '<td>', $val, '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: ? http://codepad.org/zpA4V5QF  You're also missing a semicolon on `echo '<table>' `

Comment: i must use foreach. i will get data for database mysql

Comment: @Remind: you should say things like that from the get-go. You don't go to the doctor for a bandaid and then tell him you've got an axe wound in your head as you walk out the door...

Comment: for edit: this has one column - from top to bottom, but i have for example 12 column. for example table 12x12, but not 1x244

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern of desired output is misleading.  This is the best I can do.

```
<?php

    $arr = range(1, 12);

?>
<table>

    <?php

        foreach ($arr as $value) {

            echo '<tr>';

            echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';

            foreach (range(1, 9) as $i) {

                echo '<td>' . $i . $value . '</td>';
            }

            echo '</tr>';
        }

    ?>

</table>
```

Output:

```
1   11  21  31  41  51  61  71  81  91
2   12  22  32  42  52  62  72  82  92
3   13  23  33  43  53  63  73  83  93
4   14  24  34  44  54  64  74  84  94
5   15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85  95
6   16  26  36  46  56  66  76  86  96
7   17  27  37  47  57  67  77  87  97
8   18  28  38  48  58  68  78  88  98
9   19  29  39  49  59  69  79  89  99
10  110 210 310 410 510 610 710 810 910
11  111 211 311 411 511 611 711 811 911
12  112 212 312 412 512 612 712 812 912
```

Comment: Because that's what the output would be following your pattern.  What would you like it to be instead?  Please update your answer.

Comment: i get values for database, list of city in USA place sequentially from top to bottom, but not from left to right